# Цикл в python, не получается правильно получить индексы выходного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть такие массивы:

```py
r1 = [2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, -1]
t = [2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1]
```

Я их попарно вычел, получил:

```py
er = [0, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, -3, 0]
```

А теперь хочу вывести индексы тех элементов, отличные от нуля, но выводит вот такое:

```py
[1, 6, 1]
```

`1` и `6` правильно, а почему в конце `1` тоже?

***Код:***

```py
zc = []

r1 = r[:-1]
t = r[1:]

print(r1)
print(t)

er = [(t - r1) for t, r1 in zip(t, r1)]
print(er)

for i in er:
    if i != 0:
        zc.append(er.index(i))

print(zc)
```

Comment: там в вопросе ошибся, не попарно сложил, а попарно вычел

Comment: Если что, Вы можете внести уточнения в свой вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: @nomnoms12 спасибо, не видел просто кнопку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего в данном случае воспользоваться конструкцией for i in range(n):

```
for i in range(len(er)):
    if er[i] != 0:
        zc.append(i)
```

А в вашем коде вы получаете список с лишней, по вашему мнению, единицей в конце, ибо элементов, равных -3 в вашем списке несколько, и метод index находит индекс первого из них.

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, работает, просто не знал ,что index  находит индекс первого из них